# Trigonometric indentity proof by induction?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, induction

Let $\alpha =\frac{\pi}{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}, n \ge 3$ Prove that:
$$\sin\alpha\sin2\alpha + \sin2\alpha\sin3\alpha + \ldots + \sin(n-2)\alpha\sin(n-1)\alpha = \frac{n}{2}\cos\alpha$$

The problem is from a high school trigonometry workbook.

I attempted to use induction and successfully proved the base case; however, I am uncertain about the induction hypothesis because $\alpha$ is also expressed in terms of $n$. Will it work? If I assume that the statement is true for a natural number $n$ and try proving the case for $n + 1$, can I actually use the hypothesis? Or would a different approach be more suitable?

Hope someone can help! Thanks!

Comment: In principle there's no reason why induction can't work (so long as you keep track of $\alpha$ as a function of $n$, but I expect it's easier to use the standard formula for products of the form $\sin A\,\sin B$

Comment: @coffeemath  But it's a different $\alpha$. The formula for $\frac {\pi}{n-1}$ doesn't obviously help you with $\frac {\pi}n$.

Comment: The induction step would be to prove $\sin\frac \pi n\sin \frac {2\pi}n + ..+\frac{n-2}\sin\frac{\pi}n\sin{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi}n=\frac n2\cos\frac \pi n \implies \sin\frac \pi {n+1}\sin \frac {2\pi}{n+1} + ..+\frac{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi}{n+1}\sin{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi}{n+1}=\frac {n+1}2\cos\frac \pi {n+1}$.  In theory there's no reason that *can't* be proven so the answer is "yes it will work" (It's not like induction is magic and works in some situations but not others) but in practicality... that looks like a nightmare

Comment: This actually looks like the only way to prove the induction step is to prove the whole result first and apply it to the induction step.